# How can I bind Label text to a Function in Python Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a function I want to bind to a Label in kivy which should return the current month clicked by the user but it is not displaying on the screen.
The kv file looks like this:

```
FloatLayout:
    Label:

        text: str(root.current_month_val)
        textsize:100
        pos:200,500
        size_hint:0.3,0.08
```

Also the .py file looks like this:

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):

    def Pressbutton(self,button):
        global butt
        butt =button
    
        return butt

class ThirdScreen(Screen):
   
    current_month_val = StringProperty(FirstScreen().Pressbutton(butt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code:

```
current_month_val = StringProperty(FirstScreen().Pressbutton(butt))
```

sets `current_month_val` to a `StringProperty` with a value of whatever `FirstScreen().Pressbutton(butt)` returns. Once that value is calculated, there is no automatic mechanism to update `current_month_val`. If you want that value to be updated, you must update its value when appropriate.

Comment: I dont get your explanation about how to update it please

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I cannot be specific. But you mentioned "the current month clicked by the user". When the user performs that action, then you can update the `current_month_val` by simply using "current_month_val = some_new_value".